# how to get django field type instead of database field type

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following code for my url field:

```
model =  MyModel()
field = model._meta.get_field_by_name('my_url_field')[0]
my_type = field.get_internal_type()
print my_type
```

This prints:

```
CharField
```

How can I get the django value of URLField?

Comment: what do you mean by 'value' exactly? do you want a string that says "URLField" or the actual class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the only way to achieve what you want would be to do this:

```
>>> model = MyModel()
>>> field = model._meta.get_field_by_name('my_url_field')[0]
>>> print field.__class__.__name__
'URLField'
```